# Update value on read with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to update the number of views when I read a news from the database so I can know how many people has read it.

To read the news I have (using Automapper):

```
    public virtual ActionResult Detail(string urlSlug)
    {
        NewsDetailVM vm = db.News.Where(n => n.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug)).Project().To<NewsDetailVM>().FirstOrDefault();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

The Domain Entity News is:

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePostedOn { get; set; }
    public bool Popular { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to do a Select Update so I can add +1 to the Views property?

Comment: Using only entity-framework you'll have to write code that on read increments the value of views and calls `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Hi thanks. So you suggest that I read the entity, update the value and SaveChanges? I can't do it in the line I have?

Answer (score 0):

Using only entity-framework you'll have to write code that on read increments the value of views and calls SaveChanges().

> I can't do it in the line I have?

No, you'll have to write something like:

```
var news = db.News.Where(n => n.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug))
  .ToList();

foreach(var new in news)
{
  new.Views += 1;
}
db.SaveChanges();

NewsDetailVM vm = news.Project().To<NewsDetailVM>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Realize that if you are pulling back hundreds or more records that the `SaveChanges();` will take a considerable amount of time and the code will need to be updated to do smaller batches (dependant on the speed of your SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it, either by a direct query (using `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand`), something like:

```
// beware of sql injections
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE News SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE urlSlug = '{0}'", urlSlug);
```

And there is also [Entity Framework Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) which should allow bulk updates, which allows to do expressions on an `IQueryable`, something like:

```
var newsFilter = db.News.Where(n => n.UrlSlug.Equals(urlSlug))
db.News.Update(newsFilter, t => t.View = t.View + 1);
```

You could project it afterwards like you are doing, without the need to define the same `IQueryable` twice, like:

```
NewsDetailVM vm = newsFilter.Project().To<NewsDetailVM>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but the Update is not recognized by EF :(

Comment: For the direct query, no, it won't. Direct updates on the store are not change tracked by Entity Framework, you'd need to refresh from the store to see the changes reflected in your entities

Comment: Are you talking about the "db.News.Update" operation?

Comment: For the `db.News.Update` method you'd need the Entity Framework Extended library which I linked on the answer (and have a `using EntityFramework.Extensions` clause)